# Trying to append a function with jquery, It didn't append. Why?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, gantt-chart

I know this is a very basic question but I really find it hard to solve.
I can't append this `$(".gantt")`

```
$("#gant_chart").append($(".gantt").gantt({

        source: [{
            name:  maintasks_val.task_name,
            desc: "",
            values: [{
                from: "/Date("+maintasks_val.time_start+")/",
            to: "/Date("+maintasks_val.time_end+")/",
            label: maintasks_val.task_name,
            customClass: "ganttRed"
        }],   
}); );
```

I know there's something wrong in it. I think I cant append like that. Is there any other solution for this?

thanks in advance for those who answers.

Comment: Provide your http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You should remove the first `;`, here `}); );`, it just throws an error. [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: @user3302093 : of course there is something wrong with it, which is why it is not working. What are you actually trying to do? where is the html?

Comment: You're doing what now? Appending is for DOM nodes, not for functions, does the plugin return the DOM node!

Comment: @TilwinJoy, I'm trying to append `$(".gantt")` with the resources in it. Because it only prints 2, if I have 5 elements it only gets the last 2 elements. `.gantt` is not a jquery function, it's a plugin.

Comment: Does the element with class `.gantt` even exist at this point in the code?  Also, the code above will only work if the `.gantt` plugin correctly returns `$(this)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using, say,  `.each` after the append *then* apply the - `.gant`

```
$(".gantt").appendTo($("#gant_chart")).each(function() {

    $(this).gant( ...
    /* apply the '.gant' to 'each' '.gant' that was 'appendedTo' '#gant_chart' */
```

Update: Another more stepped version for all '.gant' elements, regardless of where they are ( *appended* ) in the DOM

```
/* first append */
  var _gants = $(".gant");
  $("#gant_chart").append(_gants);

/* then apply '.gant'  */
   _gants.gant({ ...
```

---

You were infact trying to 'append' the function return ( that may not be a node / or jquery object) - *thanks to @undefined for clearing some possible confusion here*

---

Update : Using `.appendTo()` - will return the `.gant` nodes you want, so you can make use of `$(this)`

Comment: How do you append a function? Do you mean "You were appending the _retuned value_ of the function"?, if the method returns a jQuery object, the only problem here is syntax errors.

Comment: @undefined, exactly, makes no sense. OP was attempting to 'append' a function.

Comment: Logic **Step 1)** Append all the `.gant` elements into `#gant_chart` - step 2) Then apply the `.gant` to the appended '.gants` - ill update with another way to simplify ..

Comment: @undefined, yes too right *if* the `.gant` returned a node, it is fine. But either way - mixing it up like this is just ergghh ( imo ) -1) do the appending, 2) then apply the `.gant` seems the most sensible - and easier to track down the syntax errors.